# TestStack.White How to click on Hyperlink Located in a Document in WinForm Application

Tags: c#, winforms, hyperlink, white-framework

I m trying to do some automation tests in 1 application using TestStack.White framework , and i can t find a solution on how to click on a hyperlink located in one Document.
document.logstructure() :

```
AutomationId: linkTexts
ControlType: ControlType.Document
Name: Perform an action on event#LinkId=1
      from devices/recording server/management server#LinkId=2

HelpText: 
Bounding rectangle: 354,563,570,151
ClassName: WindowsForms10.RichEdit20W.app.0.ca490a_r12_ad1
IsOffScreen: False
FrameworkId: WinForm
ProcessId: 6816

System.Windows.Automation.ScrollPattern
System.Windows.Automation.TextPattern
```

UISpy :
[UISpy view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmwTw.png)

And pic of hyperlink:
[Picture of hyperlink located in app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aK4W.png)

Thank you !

Comment: Is it possible within your code to assign a Name value to the document at runtime?

Comment: I can use document.Name.Contains("event") or ("linkId=1") and evaluate to TRUE but i can`t perform click on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of searching , the best solution I could find is this:

```
         {
            ...  
            //Get document container
            var document = _modalWindow.Get(SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId(Config.DocumentRulesEvent));

            // Get document's bounding Rectangle
            string rightCorner = document.Bounds.Right.ToString();
            string leftCorner = document.Bounds.Left.ToString();
            string topCorner = document.Bounds.Top.ToString();
            string bottomCorner = document.Bounds.Bottom.ToString();
            // Hardcoded percent of x and y
            int percentX = 22;
            int percentY = 7;


            GetCoordinatesFromBoundingRectangle(rightCorner, leftCorner, topCorner, bottomCorner, percentX, percentY);
        }

        public void GetCoordinatesFromBoundingRectangle(string rightCorner, string leftCorner, string topCorner, string bottomCorner, int percentX, int percentY)
        {

            // transform strings to integre    
            int a = Int32.Parse(rightCorner);
            int b = Int32.Parse(leftCorner);
            int c = Int32.Parse(topCorner);
            int d = Int32.Parse(bottomCorner);

            // Calculate X from AB segment
            int x = (a - b) * percentX;
            x = x / 100;
            x = b + x;

            //Calculate Y from CD segment
            int y = (d - c) * percentY;
            y = y / 100;
            y = c + y;

            ClickOnPoint(x, y);


        }

        // Method that moves mouse to x and y and click
        public void ClickOnPoint(int x, int y)
        {
            var pointClick = new System.Windows.Point(x, y);
            Mouse.Instance.Click(MouseButton.Left, pointClick);
        }
```